# Crystal Reports (CR13) and Dataset (Command)

Tags: crystal-reports

Your help is needed.

I am Using .Net 4.5 and CR13. I've created two reports using OLEDB(SQL Server 2012), with SQL command as source. I wanted to add second report as a sub-report to the first one. For the testing purpose, I just inserted second report to first as sub-report with no link. While in the design time everything works perfect(both reports shows all data according to the command), but in the run-time sub-report shows no records for the same command.

NOTE: I am not using any parameters for the testing purpose (Will be using later on if everything is a good to go)

Thank You

Jason

Comment: How do you run the report in runtime ? Are you using a viewer or another application which is setting the connection ? Do you use  the same database connection ?

Comment: I am using crystal report viewer. But the data source of the report is set to a DataSet which contains the result of SQL Query. I am using same connection.

Comment: My Code outline is as follows;
`code`
Dim DSSetMain As DataSet
Dim DSSetSub As DataSet
Dim objRPT As New rptSessionView '(MainReport Object)

DSSetMain = DBc.SelectDA("QUERY FOR MAIN REPORT")
objRPT.SetDataSource(DSSetMain .Tables(0))

DSSetSub = DBc.SelectDA("QUERY FOR SUB REPORT")
objRPT.Subreports(0).SetDatabaseLogon(gblUSR, gblPWD, gblSRVR, gblSRVRDB)
objRPT.Subreports(0).SetDataSource(DSSetSub)

Me.crvTraining.ReportSource = objRPT '(crvTraining is ReportViewer)
Me.crvTraining.Refresh()